# Android how to set height of linear layout as listview elements?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-linearlayout

Android how to set the height of linear layout as listview elements? 
I am using listview with linear layout, so I can do for that. please help me.
how can I solve it?
Android how to set the height of linear layout as listview elements? 
I am using listview with linear layout, so I can do for that. please help me.
how can I solve it?

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/relative"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/shap">

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                android:visibility="gone"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="51dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="147dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/lout"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="More Related Products"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textAlignment="center"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/product_list"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lout">
            </ListView>

        </LinearLayout>
```

[image: in this image last view is listview]

Comment: please share the design which you want to implement

Comment: which linear layout are you talking about?

Comment: check relative id linear layout @rya

Comment: @hasan_shaikh i want linear layout with set height auto as listview elements

Comment: Very confusing . Which `LinearLayout` ? If you set second  `LinearLayout` height the `ListView` will be `GONE` out of the screen cause parent is also `LinearLayout`. Please explain the issue or show the expected output . And the outer `LinearLayout` will automatically adjust height cause its `wrap_content`

Comment: i am put the listview in first one linerlayout so solve that problam @ADM

Comment: Please share the design. And be more specific while asking questions. Your question is confusing

Comment: image Added @hasan_shaikh

Comment: @SoniyaJoshi if i understood correctly . You want your complete layout to scroll . For this make your upper part as `ListView's` Header then it will be part of `ListView`. Or you can use `RecyclerView` which allow multiple layouts in Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this,

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/product_list"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lout">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

This will wrap your linearlayout to list view

Answer (score 0):

It is bad practise to set listView height to wrap_content as it will always call notifydatasetchanged(). You must to make it match_parent. And then your layout height will be the same as listView.

You can try something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/product_list"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lout">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Or something like:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        //TO DO: YOUR CONTENT HERE

    </LinearLayout>
<ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/product_list"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lout">
        </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```